# Perl File Read: multiple lines combined while reading in list context

Tags: perl

I am reading a file using the following code:

```
open ($myfile, "<file.txt") or die "Could not open the file";

@lines = <$myfile>;

foreach $line (@lines){
    print $line;
}

close myfile;
```

The contents of the file are:

```
Crossroads Blues
Terraplane Blues
Come on in My Kitchen
Walking Blues
Mister Jelly Roll Maker
Last Fair Deal Gone Down
32-20 Blues
Kindhearted Woman Blues
If I Had Possession Over Judgement Day
Preaching Blues
Blind Willie's Blues
When You Got a Good Friend
Rambling on My Mind
Stones in My Passway
Wild Jelly Roll Blues
Traveling Riverside Blues
Roll My Jellyroll
Milkcow's Calf Blues
Me and the Devil Blues
Hellhound on My Trail
```

But the output of the program is:

```
Hellhound on My Trailsuesdudgement Day
```

It looks like the code reads only one line, and replaces the first characters with the new line that is read. I have tried different files. Only one line is printed, which is basically aggregated over all the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original file has just a carriage-return (CR) at the end of each line when it should have a linefeed (LF) or possibly both CR and LF if it originated from a  Windows system and you are reading it on Linux

Without any newlines to split up the data, `@lines` has only a single element which contains the entire file contents

Printing that text to the terminal results in all of the lines being displayed on top of one another as you have seen

You need to fix the creation of your file, but in the mean time you can read it correctly by changing Perl's record separator `$/` like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die "Could not open the file: $!";

my @lines = do {
    local $/ = "\r";
    <$fh>;
};

chomp @lines;

print "$_\n" for @lines;
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Learned a lot. 
As you would tell, I'm a beginner Perl coder. Could you suggest me any Perl practice resources? I am currently using Wiley - [link](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/compbooks/chapman/perl/exercises.html)

Any other resources will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Aditya: I'm pleased to help. There are several sites like [**Project Euler**](https://projecteuler.net/archives) and [**HackerRank**](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains) which have very useful exercises at all levels. Once you become more proficient it is a good idea to try answering questions here on Stack Overflow where you will get feedback if your code is especially good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check your original script and posted script are same.**
You did mention the last line is only printing by your example program. It won't. It will print the whole lines.

Always put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in top of the program.

Then storing the whole file into an array then read from an array is a very poor method. Use while loop instead.

```
open ($myfile, "<","file.txt") or die "Could not open the file";

 while(<$myfile>)
 {
     print ; # Data are store into the default variable $_. So no need to mention the $_ in print statement.

 }
```

The below script will produce the your mentioned output.

```
foreach (@lines)
{
   $line = $_; # this or
   @new = $_; # this
}
print $line;  #last line
print @new; #last line
```

If you want to store the particular data into another variable, look at concatenation for string($) and push or unshift for an array(@)